# Nice citation search in emacs for csquotes quotation (like reftex's C-c [)

Tags: citing, emacs, quoting, csquotes

When using emacs+reftex-mode I may hit "`C-c [`" and get a nice citation search menu for `\cite` command. Is there a way to get the same menu for `csquotes`' integrated quotations (e.g. `\displaycquote`)?

Comment: The point of reftex's interactive cite feature is to help you get the bibliography key right. I don't understand how csquotes would benefit from the same feature...

Comment: Csquotes offers a couple of commands and environments which allow to specify a citation key for a quotation (e.g. "displaycquote" environment). I'd like to use interactive cite when inserting such quotations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to add to your .emacs configuration the following (for the `\textquote` macro):

```lisp
(TeX-add-symbols
'("textquote" [ TeX-arg-cite ] [ "Punctuation" ] t)
)
```

(see [AUCTeX adding Macros](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Adding-Macros) doc)

`TeX-arg-cite` should call the RefTeX citation search. It seems to behave oddly, as even if it's defined as an optional argument, it forces you to choose a citation.

The is also [a way to add environment](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Adding-Environments), so

```lisp
(LaTeX-add-environments
 `("displayquote" LaTeX-env-args
   [TeX-arg-cite [ "Punctuation" ] t]))
```

should define the `displayquote` environment according to the documentation, but for some reasons, that doesn't work for me.

As explained in the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Style-Files), it would be cleaner to do this in a style hook to define the commands only for buffers that actually use the *csquotes* package:

```lisp
(TeX-add-style-hook
 "csquotes"
 (lambda ()
   (TeX-add-symbols
    '("textquote" [ TeX-arg-cite ] [ "Punctuation" ] t)
    )
   (LaTeX-add-environments
    `("displayquote" LaTeX-env-args
      [TeX-arg-cite [ "Punctuation" ] t])
    )
   )
 )
```

However, you should check that you do not override some AUCTeX default when doing this.

---

The not so clean way of doing it would be to hack a new cite format for the quotation by specifying a new [reftex-cite-format](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex/reftex_60.html), but that seems quite ugly to me.