# Emacs, RefTeX and Cleveref – can they work together?

Tags: emacs, auctex, cleveref, reftex

Trying to look for an answer in the net yielded only one questions and one answer which I could neither understand nor use. On tex.stackexchange I found only this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8756/nice-citation-search-in-emacs-for-csquotes-quotation-like-reftexs-c-c) which was answered but I'm under-skilled to translate it to my case.

I want to use `cleveref` together with `reftex` when using `AUCTeX` in `emacs`. In other words, when pressing `C-c )` and finding the label I want to refer to, I want `reftex` to insert `\cref{label}` instead of `\ref{label}`.

Probably there's a way to do it, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following (untested!) code should give you the behavior you are looking for.  You need to put it in your Emacs initialization file (`.emacs` or some such, depending on your platform).

```lisp
(defun reftex-format-cref (label def-fmt)
  (format "\\cref{%s}" label))
(setq reftex-format-ref-function 'reftex-format-cref)
```

(The trivial code for the `defun` was modified from the `reftex-ref.el` file distributed with Emacs.)

Comment: This used to work for me, but since upgrading to Emacs 24.3 and auctex 11.87, it no longer works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

Since [you seem to already be using *YASnippet*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27241/entering-math-mode-in-auctex-using-and) it might be better to  implement this via YASnippet instead of via AUCTeX.

Here is an example of such a snippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: cleveref \cref
# key: rf
# --
\cref{${1:label$(unless yas/modified-p (reftex-reference nil 'dont-insert))}}$0
```

Using this you write "rf" and when you expand it (default is to expand with <kbd>Tab</kbd>) RefTeX will ask you for what label to refer to and insert that label as an argument of `\cref`.

One of the benefits of using YASnippets is that you can have more than one alternative for the *same* key. For example if you use the above snippet you may also want to use the following for the cases where the cross-reference starts a sentence:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: cleveref \Cref
# key: crf
# --
\Cref{${1:label$(unless yas/modified-p (reftex-reference nil 'dont-insert))}}$0
```

Now when you write "rf" and expand it you get to choose whether you want it to expand to `\cref` or `\Cref`:

[image: Choosing between \cref and \Cref in YASnippet]

For more cross-reference snippets see https://github.com/Sleft/yasnippet-latex-mode/tree/master/cross-reference.

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays (RefTex version 24.3), the function is called with three parameters: `label`, `def-fmt`, and `ref-style`. You can safely ignore the new one, so this should work:

```lisp
(defun reftex-format-cref (label def-fmt ref-style)
  (format "\\cref{%s}" label))
(setq reftex-format-ref-function 'reftex-format-cref)
```

However, there is a better answer provided in this (duplicate) [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119253/cleveref-auctex-and-reftex-set-up/119273#119273).

Comment: For me this worked while the supposedly better answer did not.