# Entering math mode in AUCTeX using \( and \)

Tags: math-mode, emacs, auctex

As pointed out in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to/513#513), using `\(` and `\)` in order to enter inline math mode in LaTeX is the recommended practice. However, this takes a bit longer if one compares it to `$`.

Is there a way to make it quicker when using `emacs+auctex`? What are you guys doing in order to type it in quicker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet). awesome package for inserting snippets. there is latex snippet [bundle](https://github.com/madsdk/yasnippets-latex) you can use. Infact there is already a written snippet to insert exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: It looks like the one thing I was after. Does the LaTeX bundle include a snippet for `\(` `\)` or did you add one manually? I found only the one for `\[` and `\]`...

Comment: Yes, its already included. I type `math` and hit `TAB`. thats it. its dead easy to write a new snippet for your needs.

Comment: Thnx! `math+TAB` generates a `\[` `\]` pair - but I managed to create the snippet I needed! Thnx again.

Comment: @kindahero I would use a simpler key, as in shorter, for inline math because it may be used very often.

Comment: @N.N. ofcourse yasnippet allows you to use what ever key you want. for eg: here in this case adding a line in your snippet file makes it happen `# key: m`

Comment: @kindahero Indeed. I just meant that you might use inline math several times per paragraph and then you will be more effective if you use a short key.

Comment: I tried to write a snippet and then saved it. Worked fine. But when I quit out of emacs and come back again that snippet is gone and it no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

As described in [its documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Quotes.html#Quotes), AUCTeX provides the function `TeX-insert-dollar` which inserts the two strings of `TeX-electric-math` and adjusts point position to between those strings when "$" is typed.

The following elisp can be added to a hook on `LaTeX-mode` to insert "\(" and "\)" then place the point after the opening paren when an unmatched "$" (i.e., the "$" is not closing an existing math environment) is typed:

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
          (lambda () (set (make-variable-buffer-local 'TeX-electric-math)
                  (cons "\\(" "\\)"))))
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What is the difference of your answer to [Tilo Wiklund](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350700) ones?

Comment: @StefanPinnow My answer includes a link to the official documentation and includes code to actually implement the suggested solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can setup a key binding in your `.emacs` file. This definition is based on the one for `TeX-insert-braces` (`C-c{`) from `tex.el`.

```lisp
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook
  '(lambda ()
    (define-key TeX-mode-map "\C-cm" 'TeX-insert-inline-math)
    (defun TeX-insert-inline-math (arg)
      "Like TeX-insert-brackes but for \(...\)" (interactive "P")
      (if (TeX-active-mark)
        (progn
          (if (< (point) (mark)) (exchange-point-and-mark))
          (insert "\\)")
          (save-excursion (goto-char (mark)) (insert "\\(")))
          (insert "\\(")
          (save-excursion
            (if arg (forward-sexp (prefix-numeric-value arg)))
            (insert "\\)"))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

Pressing `$` in AUCTeX runs `TeX-insert-dollar`, the behaviour of which is controlled by the variable `TeX-electric-math` which can be set to use any pair of symbols instead of the default pair of `$`.

Comment: Pressing the dollar sign does no such thing on mine. :(