# Cross-ref an equation using RefTeX, AUCTeX and cleveref

Tags: cross-referencing, emacs, auctex, cleveref, reftex

After an updated of AUCTeX (to 11.87) the solution that worked wonderful from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16045/412) stopped working. In particular, I got the following error:

```
reftex-reference: Wrong number of arguments: (lambda (label def-fmt) (format "\\cref{%s}" label)), 3
```

As a side remark, for this solution to be usable I had to add `(setq reftex-ref-macro-prompt nil)`, otherwise an annoying intermediate menu poped-up. I guess it has to do with the update as well, but it is not related to the problem I'm considering in this question.

In turn, I found [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119273/412) (of @giordano) which solved the issue (once I disabled the previous hack). However, there is one problem left - when I try to refer to an **equation**, namely, `M-x reftex-reference RET e up/down RET`, the system inserts `\eqref{label}` and not `\cref{label}`. Is there a way to fix this? Any idea?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with RefTeX code, but I suspect that some functions (perhaps `reftex-reference`?) should be redefined.  I suggest you to report this to AUCTeX mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug inside RefTeX, fixed in Emacs trunk with commit

> Improve `reftex-format-special`
>
> - `lisp/textmodes/reftex-ref.el` (`reftex-format-special`): Make it work also for AMS Math's `\eqref` macro.

See it in [git](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/lisp/textmodes/reftex-ref.el?id=5e26d9849a79bf78fda821979fc937f7e5e6df52) or [bazaar](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/emacs/trunk/revision/117153).

Unfortunately, this will be available in the release following the yet-to-be-released Emacs 24.4.