# Disabling the “select reference format” menu in reftex

Tags: emacs, auctex, reftex

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, so if not, please let me know where it would be more appropriate.

Since upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10, something seems to have gone wonky with RefTeX.  It seems that Emacs was "upgraded" to 24.3.1, and I think this may be the culprit.

The problem: when I type `C-c )` to insert a label, instead of just going to my list of references as usual, the frame splits in half and the following appears in the bottom half:

> SELECT A REFERENCE FORMAT
>
> [^M]      \ref
>
> [p]  \pageref

If I hit `C-m` then it goes to my reference list and I can choose the reference as I normally would.  I really don't want to have this extra step there, any idea how to disable that and restore the previous behavior?

In case it matters, I'm also using the solution from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16045/4642) to make RefTeX work with cleverref.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To skip the selection of the reference style you have to set the variable `reftex-ref-macro-prompt` to `nil`, see the [RefTeX manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex.html#SEC24).  To do this you can customize that variable or add the following code to your init file:

```lisp
(setq reftex-ref-macro-prompt nil)
```

It [has been reported](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136568/cross-ref-an-equation-using-reftex-auctex-and-cleveref) that [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16045/31416) to use RefTeX with the `cleverref` package no longer works with Emacs 24.3.1 and AUCTeX 11.87, look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119273/31416) instead.

Comment: Thank you! You were of course correct, that solution that I referenced no longer works, but the newer one that you link to does.