# How to get \cref to print "Fig." in emacs?

Tags: emacs, cleveref, reftex

I'm having trouble using `\cref` in emacs' AUCTeX + RefTeX mode. The pdf shows the reference to a picture as "section 1.3" instead of "Fig.1a" (see snapshot below) as it should, when `\usepackage{cleveref}` is loaded in the preamble of the `main.tex` file.

I've read these 2 discussions: [link-1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139824/disabling-the-select-reference-format-menu-in-reftex/139830#139830), [link-2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119253/cleveref-auctex-and-reftex-set-up/119273#119273), and I have added the following lines to my `.emacs` file but can't notice any change in emacs' behaviour.

```lisp
;;emacs RefTeX
(setq reftex-ref-macro-prompt nil) ;skips picking the reference style

;code taken from SX "Cleveref: AUCTeX and RefTeX set-up"
(eval-after-load
    "latex"
  '(TeX-add-style-hook
    "cleveref"
    (lambda ()
      (if (boundp 'reftex-ref-style-alist)
      (add-to-list
       'reftex-ref-style-alist
       '("Cleveref" "cleveref"
         (("\\cref" ?c) ("\\Cref" ?C) ("\\cpageref" ?d) ("\\Cpageref" ?D)))))
      (reftex-ref-style-activate "Cleveref")
      (TeX-add-symbols
       '("cref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("Cref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("cpageref" TeX-arg-ref)
       '("Cpageref" TeX-arg-ref)))))
```

Can someone help me out, please?

=MWE=

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{esdiff}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% FONT CHOICE
% Palatino for serif & math, Helvetica for ss, Courier for tt
\usepackage{mathpazo} % math & rm
\linespread{1.05}     % Palatino needs more leading (space between lines)
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} % ss
\usepackage{courier} % tt
\normalfont

\usepackage{siunitx}
    \DeclareSIUnit\Molar{\textsc{m}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\graphicspath{{./IMGS/}}

\title{sometitle}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item bla bla bla? [cfr. \cref{fig:rame}]
\end{enumerate}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=.4]{a}   
     \label{fig:nacl} 
   \end{subfigure} \quad
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{b}
     \label{rame}
   \end{subfigure}
\label{fig:figure}
\caption{General caption}
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

=SNAPSHOT=
[image: in pdf, reference doesn't correspond to picture's capiton]

Comment: Maybe you should tell which version of emacs and auctex, which OS you are using. I won't be able to help you anyway, but maybe these hints would help some experts. Did you go into the same troubles when you compile with latexmk from outside emacs?

Comment: Your two `subfigure` environments appear to lack `\caption` statements. Also, for the overall ` figure`, the label should come *after* the caption.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issues you're experiencing are not related to emacs, and they are only indirectly related to cleveref. You need to do the following:

- In the main figure, interchange the order of `\caption` and `\label`: the `\caption` statement *must* come before the `\label` statement.
- Provide `\caption` statements for each of the two `subfigure` environments. Be mindful of the fact that the `\caption` statements must come before the `\label` statements.
- Fix the argument of the `\label` instruction in the second subfigure: It currently reads `rame`, whereas the argument of `\cref` is `fig:rame`. I suggest you change the `\label` statement to `\label{fig:rame}`.

Finally, if you need `\cref` to generate `Fig.` rather than `fig`., be sure to load the `cleveref` package with the option `capitalize` (`capitalise` works too).

Comment: Thanks for the `capitalize` hint! There's still a teeny-tiny problem I'm getting – when I press **C-c )** I get `\ref{}` instead of `\cref{}`. Also,  Emacs still asks for _reference style_ . Is the elisp code above, not effective?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not an Emacs expert. May I ask you to pose a new question that's specifically about (a) how to get C-c to generate `\cref{}` and (b) how to answer Emacs's query about reference styles?

Comment: @WobblyWindows I have just the thing if you'd like to post a question so it's not hidden in these comments =)