# ams math + AUCTeX + refTeX causing label references to always be \eqref not the desired \vref

Tags: amsmath, auctex, cleveref, reftex, varioref

As stated on the reftex documentation [“Note that this is automatically done by the ‘amsmath.el’ style file of AUCTEX, see Section 7.8.2, page 38 – so if you use AUCTEX, this configuration will not be necessary.”](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex.pdf) but my problem is that C-c ) which inserts a reference gives me the style dialogue, and I select \vref, but then it inserts a \eqref. It’s making me crazy. I have no idea how to debug and fix this, my lisp-fu is very poor.

My document uses the amsmath, varioref, and cleveref packages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried to change the code line `(setq reftex-label-alist ’((nil ?e nil "~\\eqref{%s}" nil nil)))` in `amsmath.el` to, say, `(setq reftex-label-alist ’((nil ?e nil "~\\vref{%s}" nil nil)))`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-ref an equation using RefTeX, AUCTeX and cleveref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136568/31416)

Comment: @Mico: Why is amsmath.el overriding a custom set variable?! grrr

Comment: You're asking the wrong person...

Comment: OK, I have little idea how I fixed this, because I was mucking around in the customization menus of AUCTeX and refTeX, but now when I select varioref style in the interactive reftex menu, it actually works and inserts \vref instead of \eqref. Also, I had some \newtheorem declarations before \usepackage{cleveref} but I think that was an unrelated issue. I may try to dig deeper to see what I changed that fixed it, but I’m pretty swamped at the moment so I’m not sure if I’ll ever get to this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: EDIT: Nope, it’s not fixed… equations are still forced to be \eqref but other entities like theorems use the correct \vref macro. I’ll work on applying the patch from Emacs trunk and/or then muck with amsmath.el

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @giordano was at least partially correct, this is closely related to [Cross-ref an equation using RefTeX, AUCTeX and cleveref](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/136568/31416) and more specifically the bug fixed by [this patch](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/commit/lisp/textmodes/reftex-ref.el?id=1d1aedd8510949fd03a0df9aafe2a8c90b90b907)

On Mac OS X, in order to fix it, using Emacs 24.3 (9.0) I did the following:

`Sudo Emacs /Applications/Emacs.app//Contents/Resources/lisp/textmodes/reftex-ref.el.gz`

Then within emacs I manually edited lines 836-837, deleting what had been there,

`(while (string-match "\\(\\\\ref\\)[ \t]*{" fmt)
 (setq fmt (replace-match refstyle t t fmt 1)))`

with:

`(cond
((while (string-match "\\(\\\\ref\\)[ \t]*{" fmt)
   (setq fmt (replace-match refstyle t t fmt 1))))
((string-match "\\(\\\\[[:alpha:]]+\\)[ \t]*{" fmt)
 (setq fmt (replace-match refstyle t t fmt 1))))`

Next, I saved it and ran

`M-x byte-compile`

then closed and reopened my other Emacs session.

I hope others find this useful.